# Cannot read property 'wrapup' of undefined console

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Hey all I am using flexslider in my website for slider the slider is running fine on my server at http://www.reurl.in/31830875a but when checked on local server or made life somewhere else I am getting this error in console "Cannot read property 'wrapup' of undefined" and slider is not working

Here is the function

```
function FlexsliderManualDirectionControls( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;
    this._flexslider = $(element).data('flexslider');
    this._originalFlexsliderWrapupFunction = this._flexslider.wrapup;
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = flexsliderManualDirectionControls;
    this.init();
}
```

This is just a single function out of full page code.
the console says error at `this._originalFlexsliderWrapupFunction = this._flexslider.wrapup;`

If you find something helpful please do reply back.

Incase you need full code

```
/*jshint bitwise:true, curly:true, eqeqeq:true, forin:true, immed:false, latedef:true, newcap:true, noarg:true, noempty:true, nonew:true, undef:true, strict:false, trailing:true, browser:true, jquery:true */
/*!
* jQuery flexslider extension
* Original author: @markirby
* Licensed under the MIT license
*/

(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    var flexsliderManualDirectionControls = 'flexsliderManualDirectionControls',
    defaults = {
        previousElementSelector: ".previous",
        nextElementSelector: ".next",
        disabledStateClassName: "disable"
    };

    function FlexsliderManualDirectionControls( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options);
        this._flexslider = $(element).data('flexslider');
        this._originalFlexsliderWrapupFunction = this._flexslider.wrapup;
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = flexsliderManualDirectionControls;
        this.init();
    }

    FlexsliderManualDirectionControls.prototype.init = function () {
        this.addEventListeners();
        var self = this;
        this._flexslider.wrapup = function(direction) {
            self.onAnimationEnd.call(self, direction);
        };
    };

    FlexsliderManualDirectionControls.prototype.addEventListeners = function() {
        $(this.element).find(this.options.previousElementSelector).bind('touchstart.flexsliderPromo click.flexsliderPromo', {self:this}, function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();  
            if (!event.handled) {
                event.data.self.goToTargetInDirection('prev');
                event.handled = true;
            }

        });
        $(this.element).find(this.options.nextElementSelector).bind('click.flexsliderPromo', {self:this}, function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            if (!event.handled) {
                event.data.self.goToTargetInDirection('next');
                event.handled = true;
            }
        });
    };

    FlexsliderManualDirectionControls.prototype.goToTargetInDirection = function(direction) {
        var target = this._flexslider.getTarget(direction);
        if (this._flexslider.canAdvance(target)) {
            this._flexslider.flexAnimate(target);
        } 
        return false;
    };

    FlexsliderManualDirectionControls.prototype.addOrRemoveDisabledStateForDirection = function(direction, $navElement) {
        var target = this._flexslider.getTarget(direction);
        if (!this._flexslider.canAdvance(target)) {
            $navElement.addClass(this.options.disabledStateClassName);
        } else {
            $navElement.removeClass(this.options.disabledStateClassName);
        }
    };

    FlexsliderManualDirectionControls.prototype.onAnimationEnd = function(direction) {
        var $nextElement = $(this.element).find(this.options.nextElementSelector),
        $previousElement =    $(this.element).find(this.options.previousElementSelector);
        this.addOrRemoveDisabledStateForDirection('next', $nextElement);
        this.addOrRemoveDisabledStateForDirection('prev', $previousElement);
        this._originalFlexsliderWrapupFunction(direction);
    };

    $.fn[flexsliderManualDirectionControls] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + flexsliderManualDirectionControls)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + flexsliderManualDirectionControls,
                new FlexsliderManualDirectionControls( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };  
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Comment: Well, this means that `this._flexslider` is undefined. Which means that when defining it in the line `this._flexslider = $(element).data('flexslider')`, the element being entered as an argument doesn't have any data on it under the name "flexslide". Beyond that I couldn't tell you.

Comment: how come this._flexslider is undefined i am having issue with wrapup